# Layouts in Express 3 and EJS

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

In version 3 of Express some features were removed:

```
the concept of a "layout" (template engine specific now)
partial() (template engine specific)
```

Changelog: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x

The `partial()` can be changed for EJS own feature called `include`, but what is the alternative for layouts?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems that from Express 3, layout feature is delegated to the responsibility of template engines. You can use ejs-locals (https://github.com/RandomEtc/ejs-locals) for layout.

Install ejs-locals

```
npm install ejs-locals --save
```

Use ejs-locals as your app engine in app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var engine = require('ejs-locals');
...

app.engine('ejs', engine);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Now you can use layout

```
layout.ejs
<body>
  <%- body %>
</body>

index.ejs
<% layout('layout') -%>

<div class="container">
<div class="jumbotron">
...
```

Another option is to use express-partials (https://github.com/publicclass/express-partials). The two do the same thing, so it's just your choice.

Comment: For the project in question I used `express-partials` https://github.com/publicclass/express-partials, but it seems `ejs-locals` provides almost the same functionality.

Comment: I came to Node.js recently and had the same question in mind. Yes, the two do the same thing. Thanks for marking it as answer. I'm honoured!

Comment: ejs-locals is unmaintained anymore, unfortunately.

Answer (score 17):

I struggled with this as well. So I put up a github project with an example for ejs and dustjs.

https://github.com/chovy/express-template-demo

I'm not sure the difference between a partial and an include, you don't need to explicitly pass data to an include. Not sure why you would want a partial.

But for a layout, you just specify a block like this:

```
//layout.ejs
<html>
<%- body %>
</html>

//page1.ejs
<% layout('layout') -%>
This is loaded from page 1 and overrides <%- body %> in the layout.ejs.
```

If anyone wants to add more examples, just submit a pull request.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this. And about `partial` vs `include`: it seems that `partial` was Express feature (removed in 3.0) and `include` is EJS mechanism. To me `partial` has one benefit -- it was possible to pass object to it and not expose all data passed to the view. By the way you can use it because you have `ejs-locals` in your `package.json`.

Comment: And it seems that support from `layout()` comes from `ejs-locals` that you use not the EJS itself.

Comment: Yes ejs-locals will give you layouts.

Answer (score 0):

You can mimic the EJS layouts in Express 2.x with the "include" option. See my answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12477536/446681

Comment: include is different than a layout.

Comment: @chovy - Agreed. But for basic simple purposes you can get by with includes, like you used with layout.

Comment: This is basically like server-side include back in the day, I do NOT recommend going this route.