# layout.ejs not rendered - Node.js, Express

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to execute a simple example of node.js with EJS templates. Node, or rather express is unable to render the index page, as in the following code, with layout.ejs, no matter what I do.

Here's the app.js

```
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , http = require('http');

var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8001);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
  app.set('view options', {layout: 'views/layout.ejs'});
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.get('/', routes.index);


http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

layout.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <head> <title><%= title %></title> </head>

 <body> <%- body %> </body>

</html>
```

And in index.ejs, it's just this

```
<p> Some Text </p>
```

Have I missed something here?

Comment: Layouts were removed in Express 3, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12616694/layouts-in-express-3-and-ejs

Comment: Look at the following question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12616694/layouts-in-express-3-and-ejs

Comment: Did my answer help you at all?

Comment: @JemiloII It was a long time ago, and I presume that I must have got it fixed then. Also I have moved on working on Node.js to other things, so I really can't accept your answer. I hope you do understand. Thanks. :)

Comment: If you have a solution to your question then post it here, otherwise, please delete the question. Leaving a question unanswered when you do not seek an answer is not good.

Answer (score 3):

```
app.set('view options', { layout:'layout.ejs' });
```

remove the views/ and it should work.